# How to create a List of Object arrays that has only one array?

Tags: java, collections

I have the following code snippet, which I can't understand why doesn't work:

```
List<Object[]> listOfObjectArrays;
listOfObjectArrays = new ArrayList<>();
Object[] objectArray = new Object[] {1, "two", null};
listOfObjectArrays.add(objectArray);
// works just fine

listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.asList(objectArray, objectArray);
// works just fine

listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.asList(objectArray); // *
// compile error: Incompatible types. Required: List<java.lang.Object[]> Found: List<java.lang.Object>

listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.asList(new Object[] {1, "two", null});
// compile error: Incompatible types. Required: List<java.lang.Object[]> Found: List<java.lang.Object>
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

I already saw [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514558/770927) on an other question, but the last example there does not work for me. Even if I add a cast to either `Object` or `Object[]` in the line marked with `*` I get a compile error.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(new Object[] {yourArray});`. `asList` uess a varargs argument, and so the array gets expanded as multiple arguments.

Comment: Or `Arrays<List<Object[]>>.asList(objectArray)`

Comment: Your listOfObjectArrays contains <Object[]>
Arrays.asList converts an array of object[] to List<Object>

You need an object array that's like Object[][]

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, Emd4600: It is indeed a convincing explanation, thank you!

Jorge: Your example doesn't seem to work, are you sure this is correct?

Kevin: Thank you, I've tried it as embedded arrays ( `Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{1}, {"two"}, {null}});` ) and it works just fine.

The error message is a bit misleading though, but reasonable if the array is expanded.

Comment: Please read this to understand why your array of Objects is treated as variable argument list of Objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always tell Java that you want a list of `Object[]` by specifying the type parameter explicitly:

```
Object[] objectArray = { 1, "two", null };
List<Object[]> listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.<Object[]>asList(objectArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object[]> listOfObjectArrays;
listOfObjectArrays = new ArrayList<>();
Object[][] objectArray = new Object[][] {{1, "two", null}};
listOfObjectArrays.add(objectArray[0]);
// works just fine

listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.asList(objectArray);
// works just fine
```

You need to do this. Your list contains Object[], when you do Arrays.asList it basically just iterates over the array and adds every index to the list.
Like:

```
List<T> list = new List<>();
for (Object obj : objectArray) {
     list.add(obj);
}
```

After this it returns the list. As you can see it will return List, but you require List

Answer (score 0):

[Keppil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32522523/770927) nicely formulated a line that would solve my current problem, but [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32522496/770927) pointed me in the right direction to understand the situation.

Until now I used the abstraction that `Arrays.asList()` wraps the argument(s) in an array regardless of content and then uses it to create an `ArrayList`. According to this model my call should have resulted in an `ArrayList` backed by an array containing the passed `Object[]` parameter.

Looking at the `Arrays.asList()` source it became clear that my call (`listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.asList(objectArray);`) would have resulted in a List backed by `objectArray` itself, creating an `ArrayList<Object>`. So in order to have a list of `Object[]` arrays, I'd need to pass an array of `Object[]` arrays (as Kevin suggested), or explicitly set the type parameter of `Arrays` to `Object[]`, forcing `Arrays.asList()` to interpret the argument as an array consisting of `Object[]` items (as per Keppil).